# how to put result in the end using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

my code is :
html with the js in section please ch3eck it out i need to prodeuce the result of the form of five questions and display it in the last section of the page where am i going wrong am using innerhtml js thing to produce the result in the last section

```
<div id="section1">
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function changeText2() {
            alert("working");
            var count1 = 0;
            var a = document.forms["myForm"]["drop1"].value;

            var b = document.forms["myForm"]["drop2"].value;
            alert(document.forms["myForm"]["drop2"].value);

            var c = document.forms["myForm"]["drop3"].value;
            var d = document.forms["myForm"]["drop4"].value;
            var e = document.forms["myForm"]["drop5"].value;
            var f = document.forms["myForm"]["drop6"].value;

            if (a === 2) {
                count1++;
                alert(count1);
            } else {
                alert("lit");
            }

            if (b === 2) {
                count1++;
            } else {
                alert("lit");
            }

            if (c === 2) {
                count1++;
            } else {
                alert("lit");
            }

            if (d === 2) {
                count1++;
            } else {
                alert("lit");
            }

            if (e === 2) {
                count1++;
            } else 
                alert("lit");
        }
        alert(count1);


        document.getElementById('boldStuff2').innerHTML = count1;
    </script>

    <form name="myForm">
        <p>1)&#x00A0;&#x00A0;Who won the 1993 &#x201C;King of the Ring&#x201D;?</p>
        <div>
            <select id="f1" name="drop1">
                <option value="0" selected="selected">-- Select --</option>
                <option value="1">Owen Hart</option>
                <option value="2">Bret Hart</option>
                <option value="3">Edge</option>
                <option value="4">Mabel</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <!--que1-->
        <p>2)&#x00A0;&#x00A0;What NHL goaltender has the most career wins?</p>
        <div>
            <select id="f2" name="drop2">
                <option value="0" selected="selected">-- Select --</option>
                <option value="1">Grant Fuhr</option>
                <option value="2">Patrick Roy</option>
                <option value="3">Chris Osgood</option>
                <option value="4">Mike Vernon</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <!--que2-->
        <p>3)&#x00A0;&#x00A0;What Major League Baseball player holds the record for
            all-time career high batting average?</p>
        <div>
            <select id="f3" name="drop3">
                <option value="0" selected="selected">-- Select --</option>
                <option value="1">Ty Cobb</option>
                <option value="2">Larry Walker</option>
                <option value="3">Jeff Bagwell</option>
                <option value="4">Frank Thomas</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <!--que3-->
        <p>4)&#x00A0;&#x00A0;Who among the following is NOT associated with billiards
            in India?</p>
        <div>
            <select id="f4" name="drop4">
                <option value="0" selected="selected">-- Select --</option>
                <option value="1">Subash Agrawal</option>
                <option value="2">Ashok Shandilya</option>
                <option value="3">Manoj Kothari</option>
                <option value="4">Mihir Sen</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <!--que4-->
        <p>5)&#x00A0;&#x00A0;Which cricketer died on the field in Bangladesh while
            playing for Abahani Club?</p>
        <div>
            <select id="f5" name="drop5">
                <option value="0" selected="selected">-- Select --</option>
                <option value="1">Subhash Gupte</option>
                <option value="2">M.L.Jaisimha</option>
                <option value="3">Lala Amarnath</option>
                <option value="4">Raman Lamba</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <!--que5--> <a href="#services" class="page_nav_btn next"><input type='button' onclick='changeText2()' value='NEXT'/></a>

    </form>
</div>
<div id="section2"></div>...
<div id="results">
    <b id='boldStuff2'>fff ggg</b> 
</div>
```

need to display the results of each section at the last div as shown in script...
js for first section not working plz some help me where am i going wrong....

Comment: If you're using jQuery, you're doing ALOT wrong. :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Updated <sub>Tip at bottom and new code for debugging</sub>

It seems you havn't quite grasped jQuery yet and i'm not sure what your JavaScript is supposed to do in the end as its obviously unfinished, but I took the liberty of rewriting your js in FULL jQuery syntax with some comments.  I hope this might help you some.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function changeText2() {
        alert("working");
        
        var count1 = 0, //  just fyi, you could get all the following much easier if you used IDs instead, for instance:
            a = $('form[name="myForm"]').find('select[name=drop1]').val(),  //  $("#myForm") would retrieve <form id="myForm" ...
            b = $('form[name="myForm"]').find('select[name=drop2]').val(),
            c = $('form[name="myForm"]').find('select[name=drop3]').val(),
            d = $('form[name="myForm"]').find('select[name=drop4]').val(),
            e = $('form[name="myForm"]').find('select[name=drop5]').val(),
            f = $('form[name="myForm"]').find('select[name=drop6]').val();
        
        //  First error test here
        console.log(a, b, c, d, e, f);  //  also, you dont have to use alert to test things, try opening your browsers console
        
        //  really not sure what you had going with all the if statements, but they all produce the same result, well, here ...
        (a == 2 || b == 2 || c == 2 || d == 2 || e == 2 || f == 2) ? count1++ : alert("lit");
            
        //  Final Test in console what just happened
        console.log("A-F Equaled 2: ", (a == 2 || b == 2 || c == 2 || d == 2 || e == 2 || f == 2));
        console.log("count1: ", count1);

        
        alert(count1);
        
        $("#boldStuff2").text(count1);
    };
    
    //  The previous is just a function and not applied to anything
    //  which i noticed in your code may be a large part of your problem
    //  The following is the "document.ready function (if you're using a newer jQuery version you can shorten it, but thats another lesson)
    //  This tells the html, when the page loads, attempt this
    $(document).ready(function() {
        //  the following grabs the element named "myForms" and tells it, onSubmit, do what's inside
        $('form[name="myForm"]').submit(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault(); //  this command stops the form from submitting under normal browser rules
            changeText2();  //   this calls our predefined function
        });
    })
</script>
```

> Additional Info

Also, you html for your button can be changed using the jQuery/JavaScript I've provided.  Since my jQuery code has a function to handle form submission, the input button can therefor be a normal form submit button

Change:

```
<input type='button' onclick='changeText2()' value='NEXT'/>
```

To:

```
<input type="submit" value="NEXT">
```

Not that either method is incorrect, you could still use the button onclick if you want, but then you dont need my .submit code.  Just something to keep in mind.

> TIP

It is MUCH easier to Debug using CONSOLE rather than ALERT.  To see the console in different browsers is a different process in each.  Below I'll tell you how to access the Console in the top 3 major browsers.

> **IE7+** 
>  - Simply press the "F12" key one time 
>  - Then click on the "tab" that has the text "Console" (3rd from left)
>
> **FireFox** 
>  - The easiest method is to install [FireBug](https://getfirebug.com/) 
>  - Once installed, simply click on the little "bug" in the upper right of the browser 
>  - then make sure the "Console" tab is active by clicking on it
>
> **Google Chrome** 
>  - Simply Press "Ctrl+Shift+J" 
>   - Just a tip, make sure your Chrome browser has Window Focus when you do this shortcut keypress 
>  - Also, click the "Console" tab and you can see all your consoled results there

Using your browser's console is not only a great way to debug JavaScript but it will also tell you Errors in files loading, flag potential warning on things like cross-domain issues and much more!

Comment: thanks for the reply its working but the count1 is not incrementing please can u give the code to increment the count on true cases...

Comment: That code will increment count1 if ever a, b, c, d, e, OR f == the INT 2.  If it is not incrementing then it's because a, b, c, d, e,OR f never equals the NUMBER 2. I'll edit my answer to show you how to check for that with ease and give a couple more tips

Answer (score 2):

Your problem seems to be curly brackets in the wrong place.

you ended your function too early, the "innerHTML" stuff is outside of your function. I suggest you use proper code indenting, so you see these errors earlier.

change your code to:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function changeText2() {
        alert("working");
        var count1 = 0;
        var a = document.forms["myForm"]["drop1"].value;

        var b = document.forms["myForm"]["drop2"].value;
        alert(document.forms["myForm"]["drop2"].value);

        var c = document.forms["myForm"]["drop3"].value;
        var d = document.forms["myForm"]["drop4"].value;
        var e = document.forms["myForm"]["drop5"].value;
        var f = document.forms["myForm"]["drop6"].value;

        if (a == 2) {
            count1++;
            alert(count1);
        } else {
            alert("lit");
        }

        if (b == 2) {
            count1++;
        } else {
            alert("lit");
        }

        if (c == 2) {
            count1++;
        } else {
            alert("lit");
        }

        if (d == 2) {
            count1++;
        } else {
            alert("lit");
        }

        if (e == 2) {
            count1++;
        } else 
            alert("lit");

        alert(count1);

        document.getElementById('boldStuff2').innerHTML = count1;
    }
</script>
```

edit: you also need to use `==` and not `===`. `===` also compares the type of the operands, which is "string" for the `option` values and int for your literals. 
You could also use `===`, but you need to compare the option values with string literals, and not numbers. `e === "2"` instead of `e === 2`.

edited the code above. Seems to work now. 
http://jsfiddle.net/xzP8B/